# how to extract feature from convolution layers in siamese network?

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, tensor, siamese-network

[image]I am trying to extract features from a trained siamese network, but I am facing an issue as it expects two input images and the output is a distance-vector.

```
from Keras import backend as K

outputs = [layer.get_output_at(-1) for layer in model.layers]          # all layer outputs
functor = K.function([img_a, img_b]+ [K.learning_phase()], [feat_vecs_a, feat_vecs_b])
# Testing
test = np.random.random(input_dim)[np.newaxis,...]
layer_outs = functor([im1, im2])
layer_outs
```

I am getting only distance value and not able to figure out how to extract features from final convolution layer.

Answer (score 1):

Get the sequential model and predict from it.

```
output_features = original_sequential_model.predict(input_images_as_numpy)
```

If you want the outputs of "every" layer, then do what you're doing, but with the sequential model:

```
outputs = [layer.output for layer in original_sequential_model.layers]
extractor = Model(original_sequential_model.input, outputs)

output_features = extractor.predict(input_images_as_numpy)
```

If you don't have the original sequential model, it's in the siamese net:

```
original_sequential_model = model.get_layer("sequential_1") 
    #or the name that appears in the summary.
```

Comment: The 3 solutions you suggested is not helping me, I face the issue, first one when I execute model.predict I get the only a single value that is the euclidean distance between the two images, My need is want to extract features using the trained model. When I write layer.output I face the below error. | AttributeError: Layer sequential_1 has multiple inbound nodes, hence the notion of "layer output" is ill-defined. Use `get_output_at(node_index)` instead. And my model accepts two input images so I am not able to set layer_name.

Comment: I was able to fix it, please check!  
base_model = model.get_layer('input_2')

input = Input(shape=input_dim)
x = base_model(input)

model_custom = Model(input, x)

im2 = np.expand_dims(x_test[0, 1], axis=0)
pred1 = model_custom.predict(im2)
But I have one more dout, how to save features in 128d while  registering the sample image set?